# Trigger click event on Datatables row with jquery by the row's data attribute

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables 1.10.7.  I have a table initialized with Datatables like so:

```
var user_table = $("#user_table").DataTable({
    "bInfo":false,
    "bLengthChange":false
});
```

I've written code that triggers a series of events when someone clicks a row in that table like this:

```
$("#user_table tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    // Series of actions here
});
```

My `#user_table` has rows like this:

```
<tr data-user-id="4287">
    <td>Jane Smith</td>
    <td>Senior VP</td>
</tr>
<tr data-user-id="2442">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>HR Manager</td>
</tr>
```

On page load, I want to trigger the click event on rows with the `data-user-id` matching a list of dynamically generated user-id's. For the sake of this question, how would I trigger the click event on the row with a `data-user-id` of 4287? Keep in mind, because of Datatables pagination, the row may not exist in the DOM - only in the Datatables variables - so I need a solution that utilizes the Datatables API.

Comment: Is the purpose of this simply to select the rows that match the dynamic user ids?

Comment: The purpose is to trigger the click event on the rows that match the dynamic list of user-id's so that the series of actions from the click event is performed on those rows when you come to the page.

Comment: Would waiting until the table is fully loaded and then triggering the actions work?

Comment: Yes, the table will be fully loaded and initialized as a DataTable.  Then I set the click event (which works fine using the page) and then I want to trigger the click event on certain rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use **event delegation** like

```
$("#user_table tbody").on('click', 'tr[data-user-id="4287"]', function () {
    // Series of actions here
}).click(); // trigger the click
```

Comment: How will this work if the element is not yet loaded into the DOM?

Comment: This isn't going to work. The row is potentially not in the DOM.

Comment: If it is dynamically added in the dom so only i used event delegation. if it is not added in the dom it never triggers that solve

Comment: This is the correct answer, imho - but I fail to see the meaning with `.click()`. It does not do anything at all.  To match multiple `id`'s use `$("#usertable tbody").on('click', 'tr[data-user-id="4287"],tr[data-user-id="2442"]', function () {`

Comment: '.click()' it usually trigger the click event initaily and manually

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JqueryKing. However, I already knew how to do what you described. What I'm struggling with is how to use the Datatables API to trigger the click event on a row, even when the row is not in the DOM, but rather stored in one of Datatables' variables.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved something similar to this, but I was just selecting a single row. Here's how I did it. This will look through all the rows and even will page directly to the page where the row exists automatically. Not an exact solve for your problem, but might be able to point you in the right direction.

Start with a script like this:

```
 jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'selectData()', function ( data, dataPoint ) {
    var table = this;

    this.rows({order:'current'}).iterator( 'row', function (ctx, idx, t, i) {
      if ( table.row(idx).data()[dataPoint] === data ) {
        var page = Math.floor( i / table.page.info().length );
        table.page( page ).draw( false );

        // Select row using TableTools
        var tt = $.fn.dataTable.TableTools.fnGetInstance( table.table().node() );
        tt.fnSelect( table.row(idx).node() );
      }
    } );

    return this;
} );
```

And call with this:

```
$('#user_table').DataTable().selectData( row_value, 'column name' );
```

You can get the rows selected with something like this and give you an array of all the selected rows:

```
var selected_things =[];
$("#user_table tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
selected_things.push(table.row( this ).data() );
});
```

In the above `row_value` should be a variable that you define based on the JSON values passed into the table. `'column name'` should be name of your column in the table. On suggestion to make this work is to pass the user-id as column and dont' display it, then you can use the above otherwise it won't quite fit for your need.

This will select all of the rows with the variables you want. I haven't tested passing multiple values into the script you call, but it should work with some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

though it is a late answer, you can use `initComplete` of datatables options;

```
DataTable({
    ...
    "initComplete": function() {
        $("DOM element").click(); // or
        $("DOM element").trigger("click");
    },
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#user_table tbody tr[data-inst='50821'] td.details-pmt-control").click();
```

this approach worked for me, it generates click event (in my case on specific td inside the row). 
in the tr as you see i had to add  "data-inst" attribute to find the correct row. place this line after preparing datatables and connecting events to it.